# Is there a way to find all the pages' link by a URL?

Tags: hyperlink, scraper

If I have a link say http://yahoo.com/ so can I get the links inside yahoo? For example, I have a website http://umair.com/ and I know there are just 5 pages Home, About, Portfolio, FAQ, Contact so can I get links as follows programmatically?

```
http://umair.com/index.html
http://umair.com/about.html
http://umair.com/portfolio.html
http://umair.com/faq.html
http://umair.com/contact.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Define what you mean by "links inside yahoo".

Do you mean all pages for which there is a link to on the page returned by "http://www.yahoo.com"?   If so, you could read the HTML returned by an HTTP GET request, and parse through it looking for `<a>` elements.  You could use the ["HTML Agility Pack"](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for help.

If you mean, "All pages on the server at that domain", probably not.  Most websites define a default page which you get when you don't explicitly request one.  (for example, requesting http://umair.com almost certainly returns http://umair.com/index.html).  *Very* few website don't define a default, and they will return a list of files.

If you mean, "All pages on the server at that domain, even if they define a default page", no that cannot be done.  It would be an extreme breach of security.

Comment: The last paragraph you mentioned was is my question. You're saying this is not possible but if you know about a tool named WebCopier, that does it. no?

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by a Web Crawler, read some basic information about it:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler
```

Includes Open Source crawlers, see if any of them is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I already know about it. I needed to ask whether I can overcome the default page setting in Servers?